# app terminating when getting into a exception

Tags: java, android

I have created a program that sends pictures to the smb drive and I am trying to create a textview to show up when the program runs into the exception (which is triggered when I turn off the wi-fi connection) but instead it is force closed and is not giving me any actual error other than the following:

> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 365K, 11% free 3477K/3880K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
>   D/Camera: procName from cmdline: Ominidata.Tablet
>   Application terminated.

Can anyone explain me why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    TextView txtinfocam;

    @Override        
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    txtinfocam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtinfocam);

      protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            txtinfocam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtinfocam.setText(r);
            txtinfocam.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txtinfocam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 5000);
        }

        @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                z = getString(R.string.pic_uploaded);

                      } catch (Exception ex) {
                    z = z + " " + ex.getMessage().toString();
            }
                    return z;    
        }

        }
    }
```

And my XML:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_area1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtinfocam"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Might want to fix your grammar and properly format your question. You should also provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you mean by "terminating"? If your app is actually crashing, there should be an exception stack trace in logcat, and you should include that in your question.

Comment: is also what is strange as it doesn't giving me any logcat it just closing it and giving me Tablet Application terminated. not sure if it has something to do with the way you enter the activity as you use the credential that are stored in the DB to get into that activity

Comment: `txtinfocam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtinfocam.setText(z+ " " + ex.getMessage().toString());`. You cannot do these and other guI actions in doInBackground(). Do it in onPostExecute() instead.

Comment: then how do i get the exception message up to my postexecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your catch block, use:

```
z+=ex.getMessage().toString();
```

On your `onPostExecute()` method, you will have a String a parameter. And that's your exception message. Put that String on the TextView

Comment: that are giving me a null pointer at txtinfocam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);